# How do I import multiple classes in another django app correctly

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am using `python 3.5` + `django 1.11` and I have two apps `hr` and `payroll` in my project called ERP.

On `payroll` app `model.py`  I'm importing classes from `hr` as below:

```
# Imports from your apps
from hr.models import (
    # Employee,
    Job,
    JobHistory,
    Department,
    Section,
    Region,
    Country,
    Location,
)
```

I think this is cumbersome for me considering if in the future I will add more classes to `hr` I will have to add the same classes as **imports** above.

Is there a simpler way to import them at once without adding them one by one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only use the models in foreign keys/many-to-many/one-to-one fields, then you may not need to import the models at all. Just use a string instead:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey('hr.Job', ...)
```

Another option is to import the models directory:

```
import hr.models as hr_models
```

Then change the code to use `hr_models` e.g. `hr_models.Job`, `hr_models.JobHistory`.

Finally, you could do a star import, but this is discouraged because it makes it harder to see where models have been imported from.

```
from hr.models import *
```

Note that code is written once but read many times, so it's probably worth the extra time to update the imports instead of a star import.